# Corrupted image file when using win32

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, sd-card, rpi.gpio, pi-3b+

What things make the file is corrupted and not readable as an image file?!
if the sd card is read-only, this prevent that I able to take a copy from it??!

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by image is corrupted ?

If it's an installation issue with WIn32DiskImager, here's my experience:

I just installed Raspbian on an SD Card this morning and I got an error too but went to Raspbian official doc and found Etcher which work really well and even have a portable version !

Here's the release page of their Github, you'll find what you need:
[Github Balena.io](https://github.com/balena-io/etcher/releases)